# How can I keep my accordion panels open when the page loads, but maintain its collapsibility afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

For my accordion menu, I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to keep my accordion panels open when the browser loads. I've tried removing overflow:hidden; for the panels but I run into errors. I want to be able to have my panels open when the browser loads, but let the user open/close the links afterwards.

HTML

```
<div class="sideMenu">
 <div class="logo">TS<div>
 <div class="smallSpacer"></div>

  <div class="accordion">code</div>
   <div class="panel">
    <p>uhn redesign </p>
    <p>180 websites </p>
 </div>

 <div class="bigSpacer"></div>

 <div class="accordion">design</div>
   <div class="panel">
    <p>gigloo </p>
    <p>space is the place</p>
    <p>tyler the creator </p>
    <p>nike concepts</p>
    <p>portraits/fashion</p>
 </div>

 <div class="bigSpacer"></div>

<div class="accordion">personal</div>
   <div class="panel">
    <p>product</p>
    <p>animations</p>
    <p>comics</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
.sideMenu{
 background-color:black;
width:250px;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
margin:20px;
text-align:center;
 }
.logo{
 color:white;
}

.smallSpacer{
 margin-bottom:15px;
}

.bigSpacer{
margin-bottom:20px;
}
.accordion {
color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.4s;
font-weight:500;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {

}

.panel {
font-weight:300;
 max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
 acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
 }
 });
}
```

Here is my Codepen. https://codepen.io/taniasharma98/pen/KKwQXBK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
//this is where magic happens
  if(i==0){
    acc[0].classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = acc[0].nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }  

  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, all I did was expand the accordion for the first element. 
I have copied and pasted the same code that the event listener would have executed and instead attached it to the first element directly at startup. This also helps to retain the collapsibility as the event listeners have been added irrespective of the other code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! This helps a lot. However, only one of my panels expand, not all of them when the browser loads. What code do I need to add/write in order to ensure all the panels are open when the browser loads?

Comment: @tsharma You can remove the if condition and replace 0 with i in the loop. The code should work fine for all elements then. However, I am not sure if that is the right behaviour when it comes to using accordion.